# /users/questions with content is very latent

Tags: support

I am seeing response times of up to 30 seconds for a page of 100 questions.

http://api.stackapps.com/1.0/users/14/questions?answers=true&body=true&comments=true&page=1&pagesize=100

Is this expected and is there any way the throughput could be improved?

Comment: Confirmed. Chrome reports 31.25s latency.